# sourcing a tcl file in itcl code at the global level

Tags: tcl, itcl

I have a tcl file which has few config procs defined. My one app is coded in itcl which needs to call these config proc for each object. I am not able to source TCL file at the global level in itcl. it allows sourcing only within public methods but this is not what i am looking for. I want to source the tcl file at once only for all objects and then use it till the program runs.
Any suggestions please?

thanks

Comment: I never use itcl, but surely you can `uplevel #0 [list source foo.tcl]`?

Comment: As Peter writes, this should just do it. In any case, you should post an MVC example.

Answer (score 0):

The `source` command *always* evaluates the file's contents at the *current* level; it really is effectively just read the file's contents into a string and then `eval` that (except for a little trickery with `info script`). That means that if you want to `source` a file in the global context, you should do one of these:

```
# Quotes around #0 just because of Stack Overflow's highlighting
uplevel "#0" {
    source thefile.tcl
}
```

```
uplevel "#0" [list source $thefile]
```

```
namespace eval :: {
    source thefile.tcl
}
```

```
namespace eval :: [list source $thefile]
```

The versions with `list` are doing code generation, and will work much better when the filename is in a variable (or generated by a command like `file join`); if everything is literal, you're better off using the braced versions.

The versions with `uplevel #0` are different from the versions with `namespace eval ::` in that the former goes *up* the stack to the global level, whereas the latter just pushes a new stack frame that you can `uplevel` out of. Most of the time, with sane code, the differences are very slight; use the one you prefer as both are good code.

Comment: Maybe `apply [list {} [list source $thefile] ::]` is also worth a note?

Comment: But that does something else; unqualified variables in it are local and not global.

Comment: Sure, but this might be just fine or even required in certain scenarios. And given that the question is about "config procs" only (so command resolution in the global NS), this is a viable option so not to pollute anything.